# Windsor IoC with Umbraco 7.2.1

Tags: c#, umbraco, castle-windsor

In the past I have had some great experience with Umbraco 6 and Windsor Castle as IoC. After more then a year not working with Umbraco I thought let's see what 7 has got in store (I like the backoffice!)

After creating a new project and using NuGet to install Umbraco 7.2.1 I decided to implement Windsor Castle as of my experience in the past.

After installing the IoC and setting up the installconfig my backoffice won't load anymore! See the following error:

```
    Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
    HelpLink=groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users
    HResult=-2146233088
    Message=No component for supporting the service Umbraco.Web.Editors.AuthenticationController was found
    Source=Castle.Windsor
    StackTrace:
           at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
           at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments)
           at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Resolve(Type service)
           at Project.Composition.ObjectFactory.Resolve(Type type) in c:\Repositories\Project\1. Code\Project\Composition\ObjectFactory.cs:regel 24
           at Project.Web.Composition.WindsorCompositionRoot.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType) in c:\Repositories\Project\1. Code\Project.web\Composition\WindsorCompositionRoot.cs:regel 22
           at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)
           at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncInternal(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
           at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    InnerException: null
```

I just can't figure out what is happening or what the problem is. I only have this when I load the backoffice. It crashes already in the inlog screen. 
I have already tried several thing:
[Umbraco MVC with Castle Windsor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835555/umbraco-mvc-with-castle-windsor)
https://gist.github.com/florisrobbemont/5821863
But I just can't figure it out.

edit 04-02-2015 ---->

This https://gist.github.com/florisrobbemont/5821863 is more or less what I used! What do you want to see more? My web.config the installers?

This is my boot class:

```
public class UmbracoBoot : IApplicationEventHandler
    {
        internal static IWindsorContainer Container;

        public void OnApplicationInitialized(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            umbracoApplication.Disposed += umbracoApplication_Disposed;
        }

        void umbracoApplication_Disposed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Stop();
        }

        protected void ApplicationStarting(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            Container = new WindsorContainer()
                .Install(Configuration.FromAppConfig())
                .Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IController>().LifestyleTransient());

            FilteredControllerFactoriesResolver.Current.InsertType<UmbracoFilteredControllerFactory>(0);
        }

        public void OnApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            RouteConfig.Register();
            FilterConfig.Register();
            BundleConfig.Register();
        }

        public void OnApplicationStarting(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            Application.Create();
            FilteredControllerFactoriesResolver.Current.InsertType<UmbracoFilteredControllerFactory>(0);
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new WindsorDependencyResolver(Application.ObjectFactory));
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new WindsorCompositionRoot(Application.ObjectFactory));

            Application.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "setting up the installconfig" Could you elaborate? Show us the code/config? The problem is that Castle Windsor doesn't find a registration so I guess that maybe you are not setting up all components

Comment: I have added my boot class, do you need anything more? I mostly used this link  https://gist.github.com/florisrobbemont/5821863

Comment: Also when I go to a page it self like home or something, the IoC works like a charm, but when I navigate to /umbraco/ it crashes!

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but it seems to me that you are installing all controller from your application with this line:

```
.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IController>().LifestyleTransient());
```

but your Umbraco.Web.Editors.AuthenticationController is probably in a different assembly. Try registering it explicitly, or if you need register all Controller from that assembly using Classes.FromAssemblyContaining (might be mistaken by the exact function name).

Goodluck,
Marwijn.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and use the technique described for structuremap here http://www.wearesicc.com/getting-started-with-umbraco-7-and-structuremap-v3/

I've adjusted my WindsorCompositionRoot class Create method to check if the request is for an umbraco controller, and if it is, let Umbraco resolve it. Method now looks like this:

```
        public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request,
                                        HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor,
                                        Type controllerType)
        {
            if (ControllersHelper.IsUmbracoController(controllerType))
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType) as IHttpController;
            }

            var controller = (IHttpController)_container.Kernel.Resolve(controllerType);

            request.RegisterForDispose(new Release(() => _container.Kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller)));

            return controller;
        }
```

using the IsUmbracoController method from the linked post.